# AngularFire2 orderByChild Query Unsuccessful

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I think I'm missing something in regard to an Angularfire2 query.  I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: db.list(...).orderByChild is not a function
```

Here is what I have that generates the error:

```
this.itemsRef = db.list('projects/').orderByChild('buyerEmail').equalTo(user.email);

this.items = this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(changes => 
    changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
  )
);
```

this, however returns the list i'm trying to drill down on:

```
this.itemsRef = db.list('projects/');

this.items = this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(changes => 
    changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
  )
);
```

JSON:

```
 projects
    -LXpud3uxRaTHKIRa4Da
          ProjectName: "1234 sesame st."
          buyerEmail: "matt@theInternet.com"
    -LXpud3uxRaTHygr56aT
          ProjectName: "789 sesame st."
          buyerEmail: "joe@theInternet.com"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
this turned out to be the wrong way to go about my problem.  I ended up saving the 'key' i wanted and using that to look up an object.  No need to query for a list in this case.

Answer (score 0):

for list , the following might work.

```
this.itemsRef = db.list(path , {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'buyerEmail',
    equalTo: user.email,
  }
 });
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to.  This could be an issue with Ionic 4 I'm guessing.